# Git fails initial push to new repo on network drive

Tags: windows, git, repository, push

Can you help me understand why my simple startup project is not working? I am using Windows XP, with Git installed from Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe. I am using Git Bash provided with the installation.

On the networked drive I do the following:

```
cd /k/repos
mkdir LV_Libraries.git
cd LV_Libraries.git
git init --bare
```

At my local copy of the project:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin /k/repos/LV_Libraries.git
git push origin master
```

The push fails saying,

```
"remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/pack/pack-b69cd03c4c ... .pak: Permission denied"
"Remote: fatal: cannot store pack file"
"Error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit"
"To k:/repos/LV_Libraries.git
   !   [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)"
```

I initially thought it might be a file permissions thing, but I have no problems writing or reading files to the network drive through my terminal. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I get this after I managed to hibernate my machine mid push.  Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are having problems similar to this question [git: can't push (unpacker error) related to permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025708/git-cant-push-unpacker-error), i.e. permission problems on the k: disk, possibly related to user permissions.

Have you checked the exact permissions that you have on the UNC path for folder on K:?

Comment: I think you are right. The link you provided linked to another post: http://blog.shamess.info/2011/05/06/remote-rejected-na-unpacker-error/

This looks practically identical to the error I received. Whether I can resolve the problem with the server I have to work with remains to be seen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when attempting to push changes from a Windows machine via a Samba share hosted on a Mac OS X machine.  I resolved this by initializing a SSH server on the Mac OS X machine and then cloning the project again via SSH on the Windows machine.  Hence, all subsequent pushes from the Windows machine have worked beautifully without any errors.

When I checked out the project, via the Git GUI for Windows, I used the following syntax for the repository:

```
ssh://username@machost_ip:full_path_to_project
```

The username was the username used to create the project, the `machost_ip` was the IP address of my Mac OS X machine on my LAN, and the `full_path_to_project` was the fully qualified Unix path to the `origin/master` Git project.

I did not have success with the continued use of the shared drive even after changing group permissions.  Although, I'm sure the username could be that of a user assigned to the group with write privileges to the project as specified in previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my git repository and then recreated it with

```
git init --bare --shared
```

and this solved the problem for me. Other answers mention setting config for shared and bare, but I found that only recreating the repository helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have are your CRLF settings?

When playing around with the settings, I managed to generate a change that caused an problem identical to yours.  In the end, I create a new clone of the remote repo and slowly merged my changes back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error yesterday. I am simply trying to clone one Big Git repository to my local windows machine using Git Bash 2.9.2.

After killing significant amount of time and reading above answers. I ran Git Bash as administrator and it worked like a charm. I am able to clone repository. Not sure what is the issue, I guess it is most probably related to permissions as many pointed.