# Best practice using and merging external Git repositories

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have this internal project in our internal Git-repository `A`, 
where I had to add and adapt a major part of code from an external library from an external Git-repository `B`.
I did not add the total history of B, I just added all the present code (let's call it `B3`) in one commit (let's call it `A5_B3'`)
with a commit-message explicitly referring to `B3`.
Then I removed everything I did not need in an additional commit and adapted the code for my needs in the next commit.

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5_B3' - A6 - A7
                    /*
        B1 - B2 - B3

"/*" = copy/cherry-pick/... (no 'real' reference/merge-point)
```

A couple of months (and a lot of commits to `A`) later, I need some updates from the external Git-repository `B`.
I added the remote B, and of course there are no common ancestors detected, since B was added in the middle and without history.
However, I found a [description to line up the two SHA's using a `graft`](http://morganjones.org/blog/?p=413),
so I could line up the points where the code from `B` was 'equal' (`B3` and `A5_B3'`).
I even managed to merge the changes from `B` to `A` in my local repository (`A18_B6'`):

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5_B3' - A6 - A7 - ... - A17 - A18_B6'
                    /*                            /
        B1 - B2 - B3     -  B4     -  B5     -  B6
```

But then it turns out, I can not push this merge to my remote repository `A`.
(**Edit**: the error I got was `[remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))`.)
Thinking of it, that might be plausible, because my remote remote repository does not know about `B`, 
so it probably does not know how/where to find/add `B4`, `B5` and `B6`.

Maybe I could cherry-pick the changes from `B` (`B4`, `B5`, `B6`) and add those to `A17`.
But that way there is no explicit merge from `B`, although -of course- I might adapt the commit-message.
(I know, there was no explicit merge from `B3` where I started, I'll get back to that.)

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5_B3' - A6 - A7 - ... - A17 - A18_B4' - A19_B5' - A20_B6'
                    /*                             /*        /*        /*
        B1 - B2 - B3                          -  B4     -  B5      -  B6
```

The only 'solution' I can come up with now is to add a separate '`A_B`-branch' from `A5` (using a branch-name explicitly referring to `B`),
cherry-pick the changes from `B` (`B4`, `B5`, `B6`) in that branch, and merge that branch into `A` every now and then.

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5_B3' - A6 - A7 - ... - A17 - A18_B6'
                      /                             /
                    AB3'  -  AB4'   -  AB5'    -  AB6'
                   /*        /*        /*        /*
        B1 - B2 - B3     -  B4     -  B5     -  B6
```

In the meantime also added a smaller part of the code from another external library from another external Git-repository `C`.
This will probably get bug-fixes to, so it may even double the trouble...

My questions are:

- if we could start over, what would have been the best practice(s) to add (part of) B (and C)
- given the present situation, are there other/better solutions than this '`A_B`-branch' with cherry-picks

(Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I tried to look for something similar.
I found many answers about merging projects/forks with a 'complete' common history.
And I found some answers about similar projects that needed a single merge.
But I guess I may be needing to pull in some more bug-fixes later on.
However, I may lack the right Git-terminology/keywords to search for.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your error has nothing to do with your merge. I never had such error and, without further context, this is the best I can find about it: [git: can't push (unpacker error) related to permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025708/git-cant-push-unpacker-error)

You can't push to "*server*" (git has no server, really) due to history rewrites or if your history is older than the *server*. That's all. If you pulled from *server*, did a successful merge, then push, all "atomically" (nobody else touched the *server*), it will work just fine.

So, if I were at your position, and I had that problem pushing, on starting over I would check  what that issue is and move on. **There's nothing wrong with your merging strategy.**

Also, **avoid cherry-picking**. From my experience that's usually a bad thing to do because it saves no reference where it came from (maybe there's a way I'm just unaware of). But some times, rare times, it's usefull. Then, I write in its commit "cherry picked" or even add where from (again, maybe there's a better approach, but since I rarely do it anyway I don't care that much). One thing is certain: if you're doing too much cherry picking, you're doing git wrong. Go back to [basics](http://git-scm.com/book/ch1-3.html).