# Git: can't push {n/a (unpacker error)}

Tags: windows, git, gitolite, git-bare

I have created a bare repo in my local machine[Windows OS] and installed gitolite as well.

When i tried to push the changes to the bare repo, i am getting the following error:

```
$ git push origin master

Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 293 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit

To //172.16.90.196/repositories/Test.git

 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))

error: failed to push some refs to '//172.16.90.196/repositories/Test.git'
```

I have googled for the same error, but everywhere it is end up with the permissions and it is specific to linux. can you anyone help me to resolve this issue on Windows OS.

As i am the administrator for my computer,Hope permissions would not be the problem.

Kindly help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: can't push (unpacker error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025708/git-cant-push-unpacker-error)

Comment: @Makoto : Thnx for ur reply.. But the above link is referring to the linux OS, and it explains about the permissions of objects in .git folder. I think that is not the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Check your server, maybe there is too small disk space

Answer (score 1):

login to your push destination machine 172.16.90.196.

If it is a linux machine, go to git-directory and change the permission like this:
chmod -R g+w *
Maybe you're not in the right linux user group, then you can become member of the group, or you relax the rights for all users:
chmod -R a+w *
If you have insufficient privileges to do so, you (or someone else) with root-permissions has to chmod.

If your destination machine 172.16.90.196 is a Windows machine, go to the git-directory and change the permission for your user:
Right-Click the directory, open the property dialog and go to security and add the write right for your user (group).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a permission issue, but a gitolite usage issue:

You shouldn't create a bare repo, you should declare a new repo name in your `gitolite.conf` file of your clone of `gitolite-admin` repo, and push that admin repo back to your gitolite instance.
That will trigger the creation of a new repo.

See "[Adding and removing repos](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/repos.html)".

Comment: :: Thanks for your response.. But even i am facing the same issue while pushing the gitolite-admin clone repo to gitolite instance after modifying the conf file.

Comment: @Vikky Then redo the gitolite installation http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html, and check that ssh is working properly (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts.html). Make sure you understand how gitolite does work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309

Answer (score 0):

```
git fsck
git prune
git repack
git fsck
```