# Receiving " ! [remote rejected] main -> main (n/a (unpacker error)) " while pushing .tar file, which is about 280MB

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I am new to git-lfs. I am constantly facing an issue while pushing a .tar file inside a git repository. Following are the steps taken:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.tar"
git lfs track 20209456-123558.tar
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Tracking a large file"
git push origin main
```

While executing the last command, I am getting error

> ! [remote rejected] main -> main (n/a (unpacker error))
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https:...

Please suggest some alternatives to tackle this consistent issue.

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub blocks files larger than 100 MiB.](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the accepted answer on this question:

[git: can't push (unpacker error) related to permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025708/git-cant-push-unpacker-error-related-to-permission-issues)

It might be related for your issue.

> On both local (the local that is having trouble pushing) and remote repos, run the following commands:

```
$ git fsck
$ git prune
$ git repack
$ git fsck
```